# jQuery image gallery not loading inside Bootstrap 3 tab

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap 3 framework. I have installed the **[CollagePlus](http://collageplus.edlea.com/)** jQuery image gallery plugin, to have a a masonry gallery inside a tab. However the the images only show if I resize my browser window. I've installed the plugin several times now, but the problem continues.

Try it yourself here on this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/caN2L/)**
You'll see 3 tabs, click on "Images" and wait.
Then nudge the browser window a millimeter and you'll see the images apear
Why can't I get them to load normally?

I am not sure what part of the plugin is causing the problem but using the elimination method, I have narrowed it down to this `removeWhitespace.js` script (although this is just me guessing)

```
;(function( $ ) {

$.fn.removeWhitespace = function() 
{
this.contents().filter(
    function() {
        return (this.nodeType == 3 && !/\S/.test(this.nodeValue));
    }
).remove();
return this;
}

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to reinitialize the code just add this function in the script section :

`$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        collage();
     });`